# How to use multiple loops in a single marcro sub function

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to delete to rows in a excel sheet. I have used two different loops (1st is For loop and 2nd is Do-While loop).

When I run the macro then it only execute the 1st loop (for loop) and only delete the rows 4,5 & 6 and don't execute the 2nd loop (Do-While loop). But if i run it 2nd times then it execute the 2nd loop (Do-While) and delete the rows 9,10,11,12,13.

I tried to get the resolution to run both the loops in a single run of macro but couldn't get it. Please get me the way to run the both loops in a single run of macro.

```
Row No    A
1 
2       Block1
3       
4       del1
5       del2
6       del3
7
8       Block2
9       del1
10      del2
11      del3
12      del5
13      del5
```

Code Used:

```
Sub RowDelete()
    Dim a
    Dim b
    Dim strt
    Dim endr

    strt = getrow("Blobk1")
    endr = getrow("Block2")


    For a = endr - 2 To strt + 3 Step -1
        Worksheets("s1").Cells(a, 1).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Next

    b = endr + 2
    Do While Worksheets("s1").Cells(b, 1).Value <> ""
        Worksheets("s1").Cells(b, 1).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Loop
End Sub

Function Getrow(str)
    Dim a
    Dim b
    For a = 1 To 50
        If Worksheets("s1").Cells(a, 1).Value = str Then
            b = a
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    getrow = b
End Function
```

Comment: Add this `endr = getrow("Block2")` between your two loops.

Comment: Are you trying to delete every row in column A apart from `Block1` and `Block2`?

Comment: @ David: Thanks David, even today when i again went through the code, i found the same one i am missing the "endr = getrow("Block2")". as the value of "endr" is getting changed after execution of for loop.

Comment: @ Alex: yes Alex, i was trying to delete all the row other than "Block1" and "Block2" but on the basis of "Block1" and "Block2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple way with a single loop is as follows:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim rw As Long
    For rw = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(rw, 1) <> vbNullString And Cells(rw, 1) <> "Block1" And Cells(rw, 1) <> "Block2" Then
            Cells(rw, 1).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Even simpler, if you want to delete all in column A and just leave `Block1` and `Block2` then you can use:

```
Sub CleanUpColumn() 
    Columns("A:A").ClearContents
    Range("A2") = "Block1"
    Range("A4") = "Block2"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that the row you've obtained in `endr` variable no longer exists when it gets to the `Do ... While` loop.

This is because the delete operation in the preceding loop has changed the structure of your worksheet, so that "Block 2" is no longer in the row number held by `endr` variable.

You can just reset this value as needed, between the loops.

Also, use the `Application.Match` function, instead of that custom function to get the row number.

```
Sub RowDelete()
'## Dimension your variables properly ##'
Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim strt As Long
Dim endr As Long

'## Add some new variables ##'
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rangeLook As Range


Set ws = Worksheets("s1")

'## this is the range you will look for your blocks ##'
Set rangeLook = ws.Range("A1:A50")

'## USE THE MATCH FUNCTION INSTEAD OF CUSTOM FUNCTION TO GET ROW NUMBER ##
strt = Application.Match("Block1", rangeLook, False)
endr = Application.Match("Block2", rangeLook, False)


For a = endr - 2 To strt + 2 Step -1
    ws.Cells(a, 1).EntireRow.Delete
Next

'## RESET THIS VARIABLE SINCE THE ROW HAS CHANGED ##'
endr = Application.Match("Block2", rangeLook, False)

b = endr + 1

Do While Worksheets("s1").Cells(b, 1).Value <> ""
    ws.Cells(b, 1).EntireRow.Delete
Loop

End Sub
```